# iOS core data connecting 2x master detail tables

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

I'm having trouble adding core data to a project that has 2x Master-detail tables:  Master-A, Detail-A; Master-B, Detail-B. Master-B lists items that uniquely belong to the row in Master-A. It's a to-many,  relationship from A to B, and a to-one, optional relationship from B to A. Otherwise detail disclosure buttons are used to go from Master to Detail table.

I used storyboards and unwind segues to connect the tables.  Before trying to add core data, the tables worked and I was able to add/edit items to each master detail.

I added core data and could get the Master-A and Detail-A to save data to a sqlite file. My problem is adding the data in the Master B files and use the relationships set up in xcdatamodeled file to connect the data to a the Master A row. If I set the relationships to optional, I can store data for B items but the same B times appear for all A items. If I set the relationship as non-optional, I get a 1570 error saying that a required relationship or attribute is missing.

Am I supposed to be using the CoreDataGeneratedAccessors?  or am I supposed to use match predicates?  or ….

Sorry - I'm really new to this and pretty lost.  I need some help getting on the right direction. I would prefer to use storyboards as I'm pretty new to this and can't see where creating the view controllers programmatically would solve the problem.  Most of the core data tutorials with relationships are pretty simple and/or don't use tables. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the sample apps here, they have a Company->>Employee master/detail relationship.  You need to set the content set on the B arrayController and/or when you create a B object set its master object.
http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly significant disconnect here.  Core Data is your model and you are talking view controllers.  While you use these concepts together, one does not really impact the other in the way that you are thinking.

A view controller displays data that is in your model.  It is up to you as the developer to define how that behavior works and yes you can use storyboards.

What does your model look like?  Can you post a screenshot?

Generally as you move from one "master" to another in a storyboard situation you are going to use dependency injection in the `-prepareForSegue:identifier:` method to pass the needed information to the next view controller for display.  That coupled with instances of `NSFetchedResultsController` will allow you to display the data that is in your model.

Answer (score 0):

The following link should take you to a stripped down version of the project.  I followed the core data setup using in Kevin McNeish's Book 3: Navigating Xcode 5.  He doesn't use a fetchresultscontroller - maybe that's what I should be doing but I can get a simple master detail project to work.  It's just when I have more than one master-detail relationship that I'm having problems - thanks.  https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByH8ka19v3sTZ3FHYnZ0WEVBeGc&usp=sharing